# Tell TypeScript that a variable is of a certain type without assigning?

Tags: typescript

I want to tell TypeScript that within the case block a variable is of a certain, more specific type.

I know that I can do

```
    switch (message.type) {
        case 'information':
            let informationMessage = message as ServerInformation; 
            break;
    }
```

But is it possible to do the same without any JavaScript assigning? I am looking for something like:

```
    switch (message.type) {
        case 'information':
            message as ServerInformation; 
            break;
    }
```

Comment: This is not possible, due to the way TypeScript handles variable assignments.  If you are to pass in more of your code to add a better context, you might get help refactoring into something more elegant.

Comment: @MichaelMiller correct, but there's a workaround. Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no direct way to do that like you expected, but there's a work around

```
interface ServerInformation1 {
    type: 'information1';
    a: boolean;
}

interface ServerInformation2 {
    type: 'information2';
    b: boolean;
}

let message: ServerInformation1 | ServerInformation2;

switch (message.type) {
    case 'information1':
        const a1 = message.a; // this is ok
        const b1 = message.b; // this will throw an error
        break;

    case 'information2':
        const a2 = message.a; // this will throw an error
        const b2 = message.b; // this is ok
        break;
}
```

Comment: does this really work? isn't it more or less same as OP asked?

Comment: it works, at least when I tested it on my computer with Visual Studio Code :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
First way - use discriminated unions.

```
interface ServerInformation {
    kind: "information";
    text: string;
}
interface ErrorMessage {
    kind: "error";
    error: any;
}
....
switch (message.type) {
        case 'information':
            // message is ServerInformation
            return message.text;
    }
```

Second way - use user-defined type guard

```
function isServerInformation(message: ServerInformation | any): message is Fish {
    return message.type === 'information';
}
...
if (isServerInformation(message)) {
    // message is ServerInformation
    return message.text;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the end of the day typescript is transpiled into js.

```
 let informationMessage = message as ServerInformation;
```

is transpiled into simple assignment.

What should `message as ServerInformation;` be transpiled into? Furthermore this doesn't check the type of message, this is forsecasting message to this type. If you want type checking you need:

```
let informationMessage: ServerInformation = message;
```

Comment: no you don't need since typescript can narrow type by condition like in switch case what you can see in posts abou

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about that.